# Manage/Sink RoR project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR. Actually I need to ask that how can we merge changes if more than one persons are working on a project. May be SVN is a good candidate but I am interested in non-repository mechanism.

Thanks
Tausif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few choices. SVN is quite common and GIT style repo is gaining popularity. The rails guide highlights using GIT as the version mechanism. I used to use SVN, but learned to use GIT with Rails, and by experience, find it a lot more convenient. That's just my personal preference.

However, both are using the repository approach. The only non-repo alternative I can think of is by 'communication'. This means you and your team notify each other on which files are currently being modified and then syncing the files with some local / online server.

Personally, I would go for a repo approach. Git version control can easily be implemented with [Github](https://github.com/). There are other services that offer git version control as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Christian, Yes repository is always a good approach. I was just searching if there is a way(May be some gem) to merge project from two team members. It's just for knowledge.

Comment: @Tausif: Source control is a general problem and is an absolute must in any development, even if you are a single-developer team. Secondly indeed: for the moment Git is your best choice imho. You will not find a gem to do that for you, because it is a solved problem using standard systems like git, svn, mercurial, ...